# text breaks by auto in tabularx by using \big

Tags: tabularx

My tags are as follow:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{@{}cX}
(66.0) & [ S [NP [N$_p$ Bill ] ] [VP [V$_i$ sat ]
[PP [P behind ] [NP [Dt the ]
           [N$_c$ [AP [A first ] ] [N$_c$ chair ] ]
           ] ] ] ] .\\[1ex]

(66.1) & [S [NP [N$_p$ Bill ] ] [VP [V$_i$ sat ] [PP [P behind ] [NP
         [Dt the ] [N$_c$ [N$_c$ chair ]
[PP [P behind ] [NP [Dt the ]
               [N$_c$ [AP [A first ] ] [N$_c$ chair ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ].\\[1ex]

(66.2) &[S [NP [N$_p$ Bill ] ] [VP [V$_i$ sat ] [PP [P behind ] [NP
         [Dt the ] [N$_c$ [N$_c$ chair ] [PP [P behind ] [NP [Dt the ]
         [N$_c$ [N$_c$ chair ] [P behind ] [NP [Dt the ] [N$_c$
         [AP [A first ] ] [N$_c$ chair ] ] ] ]
         ] ] ] ] ] ] ].\\[1ex]
 $\vdots$ & $\vdots$
\end{tabularx}

\vspace*{2pc}

\begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{@{}cX}
(66.0) & \big[S \big[NP [N$_p$ Bill ] \big] \big[VP [V$_i$ sat ]
\big[PP [P behind ] \big[NP [Dt the ] \big[N$_c$ \big[AP [A first ] \big] [N$_c$ chair ] \big]
           \big] \big] \big] \big] .\\[1ex]

(66.1) & \big[S \big[NP [N$_p$ Bill ] \big] \big[VP [V$_i$ sat ] \big[PP [P behind ] \big[NP
         [Dt the ] \big[N$_c$ [N$_c$ chair ]
 \big[PP [P behind ] \big[NP [Dt the ]
               \big[N$_c$ \big[AP [A first ] \big] [N$_c$ chair ] \big] \big] \big] \big] \big] \big] \big] \big].\\[1ex]

(66.2) & \big[S \big[NP [N$_p$ Bill ] \big] \big[VP [V$_i$ sat ] \big[PP [P behind ] \big[NP
         [Dt the ] \big[N$_c$ [N$_c$ chair ] \big[PP [P behind ] \big[NP [Dt the ]
         \big[N$_c$ [N$_c$ chair ] [P behind ] \big[NP [Dt the ] \big[N$_c$
         \big[AP [A first ] \big] [N$_c$ chair ] \big] \big] \big]
         \big] \big] \big] \big] \big] \big] \big].\\[1ex]
 $\vdots$ & $\vdots$
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

and the output came as:

[image]

If I introduce `\big` before the square bracket, then it breaks by auto, but It should be run on the with the text as like as the first table. Please suggest...

Comment: `\big` should be used in math mode. If you change all instances of `\big[` and `\big]` to `$\big[$` and `$\big]$`, respectively, you'll be ok.

Comment: unrelated but you will get an overfull box from that tabularx as you made it `\linewidth` wide but indented it by the paragraph indentation. prefix it with `\noindent` or surround it with `\begin{center}..\end{center}` or some such environment.

Comment: @Mico Yes, your suggestion works, thanks a lot....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for point out the overfull box, will check and fix it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(reposted a comment as a full answer, so that this query can be marked as having been answered)

`\big` should be used in math mode. If you change all instances of `\big[` and `\big]` to `$\big[$` and `$\big]$`, respectively, you won't encounter any untoward line breaks.

Oh, and be sure to incorporate David Carlisle's suggestion to insert `\noindent` immediately before `\begin{tabularx}{...}{...}`.